# Sorting Players Input

Tags: c++, sorting

How would I go about sorting the players input and outputting it in a form from lowest to highest? I was looking at the bubble method, could never get that working and wondering if there is a much easier way to do it?

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
void game(const bool& type)
{
short *playerPicks,  // numbers chosen by the player
*randPicks;  // random numbers (winning picks)
float counter = 1.0f;    // counter of number of tries
bool win =true;  // tracks win condition
playerPicks = makePicks(LOTTO_SIZE);
cout << endl
    << "You've chosen: ";
for (short i = 0; i < LOTTO_SIZE; i++)
    cout << playerPicks[i] << " ";
_getch();
{
    while (!win)
    {
        randPicks = makePicksRand(LOTTO_SIZE);
        cout << "\nTry " << counter << ": ";
        for (short i = 0; i < LOTTO_SIZE; i++)

        cout << randPicks[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        win = checkWin(playerPicks, randPicks, type);
        counter++;
        delete[] randPicks;
    }
}
}


short* makePicks(const short& size)
{
short *temp = new short[size];
bool repeat = false;
cout << "Pick your first five numbers.\n" 
     << "Choices must be from 1-55, and may not repeat\n";
for (short i = 0; i < LOTTO_SIZE;)
{
    if ((i == 5) && (!repeat))
    {
        cout << "Now, pick your powerball number.\n" 
            << "Choice must be from 1-42, and may\n"
            << "repeat any previous pick.\n";
        repeat = true;
    }
    cout << "Pick " << (i + 1) << ": ";
    cin >> temp[i];
    if (!cin)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if (validate(i, temp))
            i++;
        else
            cout << "Pick " << (i + 1) << " conflicts with a previous \n"
                 << "choice or is invalid.\n";
    }
}
return temp;
}
```

Comment: If there is a better way of doing this than using [insertion-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) *during the input loop* I can't think of it right now (but that may be my sleep deprivation talking).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the C++ standard library's `std::sort` algorithm.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(playerPicks, playerPicks + LOTTO_SIZE);
```

This function takes two iterators to the range you want to sort. Note that the range should be an iterator to the *start of the data* and *one-past-the-end of the data*. In this case, pointers are acceptable random access iterators.

If you aren't comfortable with the address arithmetic in my first example you can also use the equivalernt:

```
std::sort(&playerPicks[0], &playerPicks[LOTTO_SIZE]);
```

Comment: Whenever I use one of them, after I enter my numbers, it will loop at the beginning of where the program is suppose to start.

Comment: @SeanK_: The problem probably isn't `std::sort` but in your other program logic or control flow. If sorting is no longer an issue you might want to post a follow-up question with your updated code and stating the expected behavior and new symptoms.

Comment: So after getting it to work, I keep getting this address or something. 003D9F90 If I take the code out, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Just, use `std::sort()`. It's very simple for this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int LOTTO_SIZE = 5;

  short unsorted_number[LOTTO_SIZE] = {5, 12, 3, 45,22};

  cout << "unsorted_number" << endl;
  for_each(std::begin(unsorted_number), std::end(unsorted_number), [&](const short& number)
  {
      cout << number << ", ";
  });

  cout << endl << endl;

  //Here, 'unsorted_number' is sorted.
  std::sort(std::begin(unsorted_number), std::end(unsorted_number));

  cout << "sorted_number" << endl;
  for_each(std::begin(unsorted_number), std::end(unsorted_number), [&](const short& number)
  {
      cout << number << ", ";
  });

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest the use of `qsort`.

Define a function to compare the shorts. Use it in the argument to the standard library function `qsort`.

```
int pickCompare(void* o1, pickCompare* o2)
{
   return (*(short*)o1 - (*short*)o2);
}

qsort(playerPicks, LOTTO_SIZE, sizeof(short), pickCompare);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this - provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to implement bubble sort, but if you are fine with a slow (`O(n^2)`), look at [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). The basic idea is as follows, for each element a[i] in the array, find the smallest element from `a[i]` to `a[length-1]`. If the smallest element is `a[i]`, you're done. If `min!=a[i]`, swap them. Note that after each iteration, we have `a[0]` to `a[i-1]` is sorted. From this loop invariant we can prove this algorithm is correct.

There is an implementation in the link I provided.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I would even go about using that. :S

Comment: What exactly are you unsure of? Actually sorting? What to call the sort on?

Comment: Both, I'm in lalala land right and so, things are kind of smacking me in the face. http://i40.tinypic.com/2h58o52.png

Comment: If this is not a homework assignment, look at Blastfurnaces answer. If you NEED to implement this yourself, there are faster sort algorithms, but selection sort is a fairly easy one. It's best to create a method which takes an array of data, and sorts it for you. This way, you collect data, fill it with user input, and then call the function on it to sort. Try to follow the algorithm by hand on the set {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}. I'll do the first iteration for you. Choose 10, the first element, find the min (1) and swap 10 and 1. Next go to the second element (9), etc.